# Inversion for verb to be

Tags: subject-auxiliary-inversion

> As soon as she was a queen, she went around the country.

Can I change this sentence into ''no sooner----than''?

For example,

> No sooner was she a queen than she went around the country.

I raise a doubt that the word ''was'' is a linking verb and we can use it for inversion as inversion can apply for ''auxiliary verb''.And the word ''she'' is a weaker proper noun for ''copula inversion''.

Answer (score 2):

*BE* is always treated as an auxiliary verb, even when it is the sole verb in a clause, so the inversion is proper.

> No sooner was she queen than she went around the country.

Note that *queen* should not have the article unless you are dealing with a situation where the country has multiple queens; and you must include the *than*.

Comment: +1, although you might want to explicitly mention that you need to add **than**.